# pgfplots hangs when xtick is specified

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Consider this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      symbolic x coords={%
        {\texttt{a}},
        {\texttt{b}}%
      },
      xtick=data
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {({\texttt{a}},1)};
    \addplot coordinates {({\texttt{b}},1)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: plot 1]

I wanted to make both labels display, so I did this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      symbolic x coords={%
        {\texttt{a}},
        {\texttt{b}}%
      },
      xtick={{\texttt{a}},{\texttt{b}}}
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {({\texttt{a}},1)};
    \addplot coordinates {({\texttt{b}},1)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But then `pdflatex` hangs with

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./foo.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 3 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.revision.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.t
ex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.t
ex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.de
f)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.
tex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonomet
ric.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison
.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerari
thmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.te
x)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.
code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.te
x)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformation
s.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.t
ex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing
.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.te
x)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.
tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.te
x)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.
tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65
.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18
.sty)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers
.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibrarytopaths.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotscore.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgfplotssysgeneric.code
.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/pgfplotslibrary.code.t
ex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldp
gfsupp_loader.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryfpu.code.tex
)
Package pgfplots: loading complementary arithmetics for your pgf version...

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldp
gfsupp_pgflibraryfpu.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldp
gfsupp_pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsutil.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotslists
tructure.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotslists
tructureext.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsarray
.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsmatri
x.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/numtable/pgfplotstableshare
d.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsdeque
.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsbinary.code.te
x
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsbinary.data.co
de.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsutil.verb.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/pgflibrarypgfplots.sur
fshading.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgflibrarypgfplots.surf
shading.pgfsys-pdftex.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotscolormap.code.
tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotscolor.code.tex
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsstackedplots.code.t
ex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsplothandlers.code.t
ex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsmeshplothandler.cod
e.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsmeshplotimage.code.
tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.scaling.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotscoordprocessing.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.errorbars.code.tex
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.markers.code.tex
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsticks.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.paths.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibrarydecorations.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduledecorations.cod
e.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgflibrary
decorations.pathmorphing.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibrarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgflibrary
decorations.pathreplacing.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibraryplotmarks.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplotmarks.co
de.tex)))
No file foo.aux.
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))

Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable t
ick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.13} into
your preamble.
 on input line 3.
```

However, adding `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}` just changes the message to

```
Package pgfplots notification 'compat/show suggested version=true': document ha
s been generated with the most recent feature set (\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}).
```

but it still hangs.  How do I fix this?

**Edit:**  In my actual example, my labels look like `{\texttt{amd64-64}, asm      }`, `{\textit{this work B}, 64-bit}`, and similar.  That is, some have `tt` text, some have *it* text, and all have spaces and regular text.  I'd like a solution that works not just for the above labels, but also for these more complicated ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend *not* to use `symbolic x coords`, but just changing `xticklabels` to your needs. That has the advantage that it is much much easier to state the coordinates.

For details have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        % state how many coordinates you need
        xtick={0,...,2},
        % you want a tick at every integer value
        xtick distance=1,
        % now state the corresponding labels to the ticks ...
        xticklabels={
            {\texttt{amd64-64}, asm      },
            {\textit{this work B}, 64-bit},
            {do \textcolor{red}{whatever} \textbf{you} \emph{like}},
        },
        % ... and format them to your needs
        xticklabel style={
            text width=6em,
            align=center,
        }
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,1)};
        \addplot coordinates {(1,1)};
        \addplot coordinates {(2,1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Answer (score 1):

This works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      symbolic x coords={a,b},
      xtick={a,b},
      xticklabel style={font=\ttfamily}
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {(a,1)};
    \addplot coordinates {(b,1)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Hmm, this does answer the question as asked, but does not actually solve my issue, because I want to be able to format some text tt, other text it, and yet other text as regular.

Comment: `\texttt{...}` is equivalent to `{\ttfamily ...}`.  Admittedly, in this case the differences are subtle.

Comment: This is true; my issue was that I need to be able to mix `\texttt` with `\textit` and also normal text, within the same label, and to format different labels differently.